# R: Reshape from long to wide, order of reshaped columns as original column order

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Below is an excerpt from my data:

```
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(1:3,2),rep(0:2,4)),6,4))
colnames(data) <- c("id", "rater", "x", "y")
print(data)

#   id rater x y
# 1  1     1 0 0
# 2  1     2 1 1
# 3  1     3 2 2
# 4  2     1 0 0
# 5  2     2 1 1
# 6  2     3 2 2
```

I reshaped it from long to wide:

```
reshape(data, timevar = "rater", idvar = "id", direction = "wide")

# Result:
#   id x.1 y.1 x.2 y.2 x.3 y.3
# 1  1   0   0   1   1   2   2
# 4  2   0   0   1   1   2   2
```

But instead of the default order (order by `timevar`, i.e., `x.1`, `y.1`, `x.2`, `y.2`, `x.3`, `y.3`), I want the order to be the same as the original order the columns appeared before reshaping (i.e., all `x`, then all `y`; `x.1`, `x.2`, `x.3`, `y.1`, `y.2`, `y.3`).

I could do it manually but I have 100+ columns to reshape. I tried `?reshape` but couldn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Do it post-hoc. This isn't the same as doing it manually. If the columns are named as you show then `result = result[sort(names(result))]` should work to reorder the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), id~rater, value.var=c("x", "y"), sep=".")
#   id x.1 x.2 x.3 y.1 y.2 y.3
#1:  1   0   1   2   0   1   2
#2:  2   0   1   2   0   1   2
```