# Convert from long to wide but group the column headings

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2

I have a data.frame in long form. I want to reshape to wide, but I care about the ordering of the columns.

Here is a toy example. In reality, I will have many more groups (`grp`).

```
# Minimum working example

mwe <- "grp mean sd label

1  C90   90 19 Heart_rate
2  D20   86 18 Heart_rate
3  H09   80 16 Heart_rate
9  Z89   89 18 Heart_rate"

# Read in the text data

dd <- read.table(text=mwe, header=TRUE)
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973466/r-reshape-from-long-to-wide-order-of-reshaped-columns-as-original-column-order) solution without success.

```
dcast(setDT(dd), label~grp, value.var=list("mean", "sd"), sep="_" )

    label mean_C90 mean_D20 mean_H09 mean_Z89 sd_C90 sd_D20 sd_H09 sd_Z89
1: Heart_rate       90       86       80       89     19     18     16     18
```

What I want are the columns after `label` ordered by the `grp` then by `mean` and `sd` ... like this

```
    label mean_C90 sd_C90 mean_D20 sd_D20 mean_H09 sd_H09 mean_Z89 sd_Z89
```

I am stuck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to melt `dd` first, so that the values for `mean` and `sd` are in the same column:

```
dcast(melt(dd), label ~ grp + variable)
#       label C90_mean C90_sd D20_mean D20_sd H09_mean H09_sd Z89_mean Z89_sd
#1 Heart_rate       90     19       86     18       80     16       89     18
```

Comment: Is melt from data.table or from reshape2?

Comment: It's present in both packages

Answer (score 3):

One quick way to solve this is to rearrange the columns afterwards using `setcolorder`:

```
setcolorder(temp, c("label", paste(c("mean","sd"), 
             rep(unique(gsub("^(mean|sd)_", "", names(temp)[-1])), each=2), sep="_")))
```

This is a bit compact, so here are the pieces:

- `gsub("^(mean|sd)_", "", names(temp)[-1])` prints out the names of the variables (except "label") with "mean_" and "sd_" removed. This result is wrapped in `unique` to remove duplicate names.
- The result above is fed to `rep` with the each=2 argument so that it is repeated twice.
- These repeated values are pasted to "mean_" and "sd_" to construct the desired order of the columns.
- "label" is concatenated to the front of this string vector.

A nice thing about `setcolorder` is that it changes the data by reference, so that it does not involve any copying of the data.table (ie, it is super fast).

Comment: a bit simpler: `setcolorder(temp, c(1, order(sub('.*_', '', names(temp)[-1]))+1))`